# What is the meaning of "too on the nose"?

Tags: meaning

Casting Director say this words to Female Model:

> When someone asks, I want you to say you are 19. Always 19. Eighteen is
>   **too on the nose**.

I know meaning of **too on the nose** is **too perfect**, but how does this meaning suits here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eighteen is the age at which a person is no longer considered a minor. There are many privileges that society confers on 18-year-olds, for example the legal right to buy tobacco products, the right to leave one's parents and live on one's own and so on.

What the woman is saying is that the lie is more obvious if the age is represented as exactly the age that it has to be. If you want people to believe that you're at least 18, it's better to say that you're 19 than that you're 18.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Sure did. Now it's a different question. Basically the same answer, but now it's that the casting director doesn't want the model to appear to be a "newly minted" adult, but one who has about a year of adult experience. Now, please try to avoid editing your questions in such a way that the answers given to them are no longer valid. When you do that, it can confuse people who read them later.

Comment: Are you saying that your answer fits to any type of context?

Comment: If by "any type of context" you are referring to any type of reason to misrepresent your age as one who has recently attained majority status (i.e. is no longer a minor), then yes.